# Which deity should I pary to or mantra to help keep addictions under control

Tags: mantras, deity

I want to know about a specific deity to prey to or a routine or mantra that I should offer to keep my addictions under control. I don't have an addiction problem but I often drink and smoke. I want to keep my strength of the mind, body and soul or even strengthen it.